# Import SQL database View definitions and Stored Procedures into Github

Tags: sql, github

Our organization has a huge list of Views and Stored Procedures in SQL Server. Recently, we adopted Github with the hope of developing better version control practices.

We were wondering if it were possible to import all of the View definitions and Stored Procedures into Github as separate repositories?

Answer (score 0):

You can create definitions out of your database with Sql Management Studio

- Right click database and
- Tasks=>Generate Scripts...
- Script entire database and all database objects
- Save to file
- Single file per object

Then upload it as a new repository to github.